# How do I highlight specific Label when selected from the comboBox?

Tags: java, swing

So I have a database of users in my `JComboBox` and on the left side is a list of these users as well. What I want to do is write a program when this user is selected from the `JComboBox`, highlight him in the `list(JLabel)` on the left side. I hope I was specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test2 extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JComboBox<String> comboBox;
    private JList<String> list;

    public Test2() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboBox.addItem("User1");
        comboBox.addItem("User2");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_comboBox.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc_comboBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_comboBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_comboBox.gridx = 0;
        gbc_comboBox.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(comboBox, gbc_comboBox);

        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        listModel.addElement("User1");
        listModel.addElement("User2");

        list = new JList<String>(listModel);

        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblNewLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblNewLabel.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblNewLabel.gridy = 0;

        panel.add(list, gbc_lblNewLabel);

        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String selectedItem = String.valueOf(comboBox.getSelectedItem());

                if (selectedItem.equals("User1"))
                    list.setSelectedValue("User1", true);
                else if (selectedItem.equals("User2"))
                    list.setSelectedValue("User2", true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 myFrame = new Test2();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Will this work for you?. I don't know why you are using JLabel inside JList. So i have changed the list from `JList<JLabel>` to `JList<String>`